# A way to read(select) an image from a location

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

Is there a way in sybase where I can select (read) an image or a file from the a server or driver ?

In oracle there is Bfile , it lets me to read an image directly from the driver, how to do that in sybase ?.

Answer (score 0):

You can read/write text files located on the ASE server's host through a proxy table that is mapped to a file.

Unfortunately, there is no way to read a binary file like an image via such a proxy table or otherwise directly from SQL. Some kludges are possible though:

1. you can use BCP and a format file to read a binary file into an image column (see my Tips & Tricks book below), and you can run this from SQL via xp_cmdshell.
2. you can use the Java JVM that is embedded in the ASE server to read files and move the content into a table; that will require combined Java and SQL programming. YMMV.